# rsync + rsync failed because Host key verification failed

Tags: linux, rhel, rsync

I use the `rsync` in order to transfer files from `/etc/yum.repos.d/` to remote server to `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

```
sshpass -p $password rsync -av /etc/yum.repos.d/* root@server_one.usaga.com:/etc/yum.repos.d
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: explained error (code 255) at rsync.c(551) [sender=3.0.9]
```

as we can see above `rsync` failed because key fingerprint

so after we did the following ( answer `yes` on ssh )

```
ssh root@server_one.usaga.com
The authenticity of host 'server_one.usaga.com (43.3.22.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 08:b1:c7:fa:c3:a8:8f:ce:85:4f:b9:ac:b1:8a:6a:87.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'server_one.usaga.com,43.3.22.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

and run the `rsync` again as - its works

```
sshpass -p $password rsync -av /etc/yum.repos.d/* root@server_one.usaga.com:/etc/yum.repos.d
sending incremental file list
.
.
.

sent 378 bytes  received 112 bytes  326.67 bytes/sec
total size is 1937  speedup is 3.95
```

so regrading to `rsync`

what are the necessary flags to set in `rsync` in order to ignore `key fingerprint` ?

or dose `rsync` can ignore the question about -  `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` yes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify other remote shell for rsync than ssh using `-e` and that includes ssh with extra options so adding `-e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` will do trick.